# Evaluating cucumber tags in BeforeFeature hook

Tags: cucumberjs

I am trying to evaluate the tagged features in the this.BeforeFeature hook in world file but I am getting the error 'TypeError: handler is not a function' . What I interpret from the error message is that this.BeforeFeature() takes function as parameter and I am using the below code.
there are other ways to expedite this problem - like reading the names of feature but it will totally defeat the purpose of tags it that case so I don't want to employ that approach.

```
   this.registerHandler('BeforeFeature', {tags: ["@foo,@bar"]} ,function (event, callback) {
        console.log("before feature")
        global.browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(500, 800);
        callback();
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: or just I am guessing that because scenario's inherit that feature tag to I should just be doing the following-                                           `this.Before("@foo", function (scenario) {
    // This hook will be executed before scenarios tagged with @foo
    // ...
  });`

Comment: It's probably worth noting here that the newer versions of CucumberJS do not support `beforeFeature` and the only options now are `before` and `beforeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Since scenario's inherit the hooks from feature evaluating the hooks on scenario should do the job-

Inheritance works as below-

Feature(hooks)->Scenario(hooks)/Scenario Outlines(hooks -> Examples

```
this.Before("@foo", function (scenario) {
  // This hook will be executed before scenarios tagged with @foo // ... 
});
```

Hope it helps.Thanks